# Стили input в form

Tags: html, css, form, html-form

как настроить стили инпута что при заполнении по дефолту они были уже с определенным цветом
есть инпут с стилями

```
<h2 className='authentication__title'>Рады видеть!</h2>
      <form
        className='authentication__form'
      >
        <label className="authentication__label">E-mail
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={email || ''}
            className="authentication__input"
          />
        </label>
        <label className="authentication__label">Пароль
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            className="authentication__input"
          />
        </label>
```

стили

```
.authentication__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.authentication__label {
  font-family: "Inter", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #8B8B8B;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.authentication__input {
  height: 27px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  border: 0;
  font-family: "Inter", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 396px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #202020;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

и получаю [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а когда начинаю редактировать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте селектор `.authentication__input:focus`

Comment: Попробуйте запустить ваш пример кода в сниппете (в Stackoverflow, CodePen или другие), там всё нормально. У вас с вышестоящих элементов цвет передаётся.

Answer (score 0):

в стили для инпута надо прописать

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: #FFF;
```